# Can't Run Vue Js Method from SweetAlert2 Pop up

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog, popup

I have this vue js app with a pop up using SweetAlert2. There a link in the pop up message that needs to call a vue js method. But, i can't get it to work.

```
<template>
    <button @click="popModal()">Alert</button>
</template>

export default {
data(){
    return{
        popMessage: "<h5>Title</h5> 
        <p>I'm trying to call a vue js method on this link <a href='https://www.google.com' target='_blank' id='popLink' @click='run Method()'>google.com</a>. </p>"
     }
},
methods: {
  popModal(){
      this.$fire({
          html: this.popMessage,
          showCancelButton: false
       })
  },
  runMethod(){
     console.log("Link in pop up!");
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing:

- you're using Vue 2
- you've installed SweetAlert2 correctly and it adds a global method called `$fire` to your app (this is not true for latest version of `vue-sweetalert2`, see last note below).

---

If the above guesses are true, I see only three problems:

- `popMessage` in `data` contains line breaks, which break compilation. Either replace the double quotes (") with back-ticks (`), which will preserve the line breaks, or place each line inside double quotes and concatenate them.
- `message` is `undefined`. Did you mean `this.popMessage`?

```js
this.$fire({
  html: this.popMessage,
  showCancelButton: false
})
```

- technically, swal doesn't recognize vue components. But... we can always create a new Vue instance and mount it in any element in the page, right? Like we do with

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  //... other stuff
})
```

So how about we

- declare a vue component (e.g: `<my-swal-alert />`),
- open the sweet alert giving its body a custom id
- mount a new Vue instance in the body of the alert, which has a `method` which calls your method.

Obviously, we need to pass it the `method`, the `$fire` function and the `popMessage`, which we'll use as the new component's `template`.

You can pass it anything, for that matter, but I think it's cleaner to only pass it `method` which. once called, has access to everything in the original (main) Vue instance.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue2-template-forked-eli147?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

---

**Side notes**:

- nobody should have to guess anything when answering your questions; in the future, please provide all relevant details
- the browser console is your friend.
  It will help you figure out some errors on your own and it will also help you write better questions on StackOverflow. Providing a relevant console error/warning inside the question is likely to get you better answers, faster
- I don't know what version of `vue-sweetalert2` you're on, but on the latest `this.$fire` is no longer defined. I had to use `this.$swal()`.

Comment: Thank you! Yes i meant this.popMessage and yes, im using Vue 2. Also, i get no errors in the console...it just doesnt fire off. The pop up/modal works...its just the method that isnt working.